# MySQL Count Items In Category

Tags: mysql, join

I don't understand MySQL very well, here are the table structures I am using.

**users**

> id | first_name | last_name | username
>   | password

**categories**

> id | user_id | name | description

**links**

> id | user_id | category_id | name |
>   url | description | date_added |
>   hit_counter

I am trying to return a result set like this, to give information about the category for a user that includes how many links are in it.

> id | user_id | name | description | link_count

At the moment I have this query, but it only returns rows for categories that have links. It should return rows for categories that do not have any links (empty categories).

> SELECT categories.*, COUNT(links.id)
>   FROM categories LEFT JOIN links ON
>   categories.id=links.category_id;

How to do this query? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can't do select table dot "star" with an aggregate.

what you wanna do is something like (pseudocode):

```
select
    categories.field1,
    categories.field2,
    {etc.}
    count(links.id)
from categories
left join links
    on categories.id = links.category_id
group by
    categories.field1,
    categories.field2,
    {etc.}
```

iow: you're missing the group by code-block to get the right aggregate in your query result set.

Comment: why we can't do the select table dot "star" with an aggregate?we can do...this query will execute                                   SELECT categories.*, COUNT(links.id) FROM categories LEFT JOIN links ON categories.id=links.category_id group by categories.id;

Comment: you're absolutely right, of course. :) but in the context of the poster's background stating: "i don't understand mysql very well", i didn't want to make a longer explanation about whatever fields listed in the aggregate function should be listed in the group box as well since most people lazily write count(*) instead of specific field count(fieldname) like the poster's questions. so i went with the general rule of thumb explanation of: "whatever you select, copy over those fields in the group by block". it's a "shoddy" excuse, i realize. so sorry.

Answer (score 0):

To mold alien052002's answer to fit your specific question, the following (untested) should work:

```
select c.id,
    c.user_id,
    c.name,
    c.description,
    count(l.link_count)
from categories c
left join links l on l.category_id = c.id
group by c.id, c.user_id, c.name, c.description
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT categories.*, COUNT(links.id) FROM categories LEFT JOIN links ON categories.id=links.category_id group by categories.id;
```